# How can I find the attributes of items stored in a WFS Service?

Tags: openlayers, postgis, geoserver

I use geoserver and openlayers to display items stored in a postGIS database. Each item has several attributes, e.g. height, width, color, ...
I request the attribute types using

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=DescribeFeatureType&version=1.1.0&typeName=mytest:all",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
...
```

and get a result like

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="height" nillable="true" type="xsd:float"/>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="width" nillable="true" type="xsd:float"/>
  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="color" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Then I would like to get the values stored for an attribute, e.g. for color so that I can put them in a dropdown box and let the user create a query to find only those items that are yellow. That way, I eliminate typos in the search query that might occur if I would allow entering free text

Is there a way to do this query?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a GetFeature request and then parse the features to find the distinct values.

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a way retrieve "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typeName=mytest:all", it returns all items with all attributes but I'd only need the distinct values of one attribute, e.g. color.

Comment: You can specify which properties you want using the `PropertyName` parameter - check the WFS specification for more details